# User defined button in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, form-submit

So I am trying to make a shopping cart. What I need to do is send a product id and a quantity the user wants to buy to another file `cart.php`.

Here is a section of my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<$numOfRows;$i++){
  $prodID=mysql_result($result, $i, "ProductID");
  $prodTitle=mysql_result($result, $i, "Title");
  $prodAuthor=mysql_result($result, $i, "Author1");
  $prodPrice=mysql_result($result, $i, "Price");

  Print"<h4>ID: $prodID \n     </h4>";
  Print"<h4>Title: $prodTitle \n       </h4>";
  Print"<h4>Author: $prodAuthor \n     </h4>";
  Print"<h4>Price: $ $prodPrice \n     </h4>";

  Print" <form method ='POST'>";
  Print"<p><label> Quantity";
  Print"<input name='quantity' type='text' pattern='[1-9]{1,50}'/>";
  Print"</label>";
  Print"<input type='button' value='Add To Cart' onClick='cart.php?pid=$prodID'/>";
  Print"</p></form>";
}
```

If I get rid of the form and just have `<a href='cart.php?pid=$prodID'>Add To Cart</a>` it sends the id but I also need the quantity to go along with it.
Whenever I click <kbd>Add To Cart</kbd> it doesn’t send me to my `cart.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just let it submit the form normally. And use a normal `type="submit"` with `method="GET"`:

```
echo "<form method ='GET' action='cart.php'>";
    echo "<p><label> Quantity: ";
        echo "<input name='quantity' type='text' pattern='[1-9]{1,50}'/>";
    echo "</label>";
    echo "
        <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='$prodID' />
        <input type='submit' value='Add To Cart' />
    ";
echo "</p></form>";
```

Of course in `cart.php`, just use `$_GET` all through out:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['quantity']) && !empty($_GET['pid'])) {
    $quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];
    // do the rest of codes below
}
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

If you want use the POST method add a hidden input with the pid info. See the example:

```
print" <form method ='POST' action ='cart.php'>";
print"<p><label> Quantity";
print"<input name='quantity' type='text' pattern='[1-9]{1,50}'/>";
print"</label>";
print"<input type='hidden' name = 'pid' value='$prodID'>";
print"<input type='button' value='Add To Cart'/>";
print"</p></form>";
```

If you want use the GET method see the [@Ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997656/3653989) answer

Answer (score 0):

Your onlick is doing a method GET while your form indicates a method POST and you're not specifying "action='cart.php'" in your form tag... there may be other issue but...

try this

```
for($i=0;$i<$numOfRows;$i++)
{
   $prodID=mysql_result($result, $i, "ProductID");
   $prodTitle=mysql_result($result, $i, "Title");
   $prodAuthor=mysql_result($result, $i, "Author1");
   $prodPrice=mysql_result($result, $i, "Price");

   Print"<h4>ID: $prodID \n    </h4>";
   Print"<h4>Title: $prodTitle \n      </h4>";
   Print"<h4>Author: $prodAuthor \n    </h4>";
   Print"<h4>Price: $ $prodPrice \n    </h4>";

   Print"<form action='cart.php' method ='POST'>";
   Print"<p><label> Quantity";
   Print"<input name='pid' type = 'hidden' value='$prodID'>";
   Print"<input name='quantity' type='text' pattern='[1-9]{1,50}'/>";
   Print"</label>";
   Print"<input type='submit' value='Add To Cart'>";
   Print"</p></form>";
}
```